# Soma de n + último dígito da esquerda

Tags: c, recursão

Estou com um desafio de recursão. O objetivo é retornar "n + a soma do último dígito a esquerda". Exemplo:

Entrada: 54321

Saída: 54326 (54321 + 5)

Porém a única forma que consegui foi assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somault(int n){
   if(n < 10) return n;
   return somault(n/10);
}

int main() {
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%d", n+somault(n));//A soma é realizada aqui, não dentro da função.
   return 0;
}
```

É possível retornar esse valor atendendo os seguintes critérios?

- Apenas uma função
- Função recursiva
- Sem utilizar vetores, váriaveis globais e/ou ponteiros

Tentei outras formas, mas nenhuma devolvia o valor correto. Justamente porque não consigo pegar o valor da última chamada e só fazer com a primeira. Tentei usar `static` para contar ou divisão aumentando a base 10 para pegar o último, mas não deram certo.

Comment: Mas é possivel utilizar variaveis exteriores ? Dependendo de toda a lista de requisitos pode alterar drasticamente a solução e por isso aconselho a que os especifique todos de forma clara. Com uma variavel global exterior tambem consegue chegar lá, mas algo me diz que também não pode fazer isso lol

Comment: O problema na verdade é outro, mas não sei se pode mudar alguma coisa. Então... Posto o problema completo? Com a solução que havia feito? 
Talvez esse que eu fiz baseado no outro possa ter solução. Mas as regras são as mesmas.

Comment: O problema é outro ? Mas qual então ? As restrições pelos vistos não foram todas discriminadas. Pode sempre mudar a pergunta editando a mesma e tornando-a mais clara, assim como foi sugerido. Mas se tem outra solução que tinha desenvolvido com outro código, talvez já seja coisa para outra pergunta, dificil dizer.

Comment: A solução é devolver se n-4 se o dígito mais a esquerda for par, ou n-3 se for ímpar.

Comment: Se tem uma solução que resolve o problema da forma que esperava, então o ideal é coloca-la como resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Eu pessoalmente acho que estes tipo de desafios que forçam uma solução especifica recursiva não são muito bons, e acabam gerando código bastante não intuitivo e incomum, e que no fim não tem aplicabilidade no mundo real.

Ainda assim se nada é indicado em relação ao numero de parametros da função então pode passar receber dois parametros, em que passa o mesmo numero nos dois. Num deles vai caminhando até chegar ao primeiro digito e no outro mantem o numero original para a soma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somault(int n, int original){
   if(n < 10) return n + original;
   return somault(n/10, original);
}

int main() {
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%d", somault(n, n));
   return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/m4oOsB)

Reforçando, isto não teria nenhuma utilidade em código real, mas cumpre com os requisitos que indicou, e gera a resposta esperada.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int somault(int n){
   if(n/10 < 10) return n-n/10;
   return n+(n/10-somault(n/10));
}

int main() {
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%d", somault(n));
   return 0;
}
```

Explicarei depois o funcionamento.